# How to query a directory uri obtained from drag & drop to get its files

Tags: android

So my app registered a drag listener. When I drag a directory/folder from Android Files app to my app, I should be able to query the uri so as to get the files in that directory. However I failed to figure out a way to achieve this.

The following throws operation not supported exception:

```
val doc = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, itemUri)!!
doc.listFiles()
```

The following throws cannot find the root of the tree exception:

```
val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(doc.uri)
val treeUri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri("${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileProvider", docId)
val childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(treeUri, docId)
val childCursor = contentResolver.query(childrenUri, columns, null, null, null)
```

This is the drag listener:

```
val apkDisplayDragListener = object : View.OnDragListener{
    var permission: DragAndDropPermissions? = null
    override fun onDrag(v: View?, event: DragEvent?): Boolean {
        event ?: return false
        when (event.action) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> X.toast(context, R.string.apiDragDropHint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                permission = activity?.requestDragAndDropPermissions(event)
                dragDropAction(context, event.clipData)
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> permission?.release()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

This is the operation on the acquired uri:

```
val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
```

When `contentResolver.query()` gets invoked, the following exception gets thrown:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider uri `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msd%3A530680` from pid=30949, uid=10525 requires that you obtain access using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or related APIs

Tested on API 27 and 29.
Evidently I cannot use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.
Tried some other methods but none of them worked.

Comment: Have you take runtime permission?

Comment: @Kabir Yes. It is an Android Q device. The issue may be related to Scoped Storage.

Comment: DId you solve this?

Comment: @Dantalian I previously had some issue with `Activity.requestDragAndDropPermissions(DragEvent)`, the read permission got released before I attempted to read the file and I fixed it today. Now I am having trouble converting the original uri to a tree uri. I am using `DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(...)` to obtain tree uri but the result uri is inaccessible. Invoking `ContentResolver.query(...)` on it would throw `SecurityException`.